# После обновление Ubuntu 18.04 не загружается загрузчик grub

Tags: ubuntu

Я обновил Ubuntu 18.04 и там предлагалось перезагрузить компьютер, но я не перезагружал, а вместо этого завершил процесс(думаю не из-за этого), утром встаю не загружается загрузчик grub..

*Выдает такую ошибку(не может найти EFI файл, что-то видимо) и буквально через 3-4 секунд выключается совсем:*

```
Filed to open \EFI\BOOT\mmx64.efi - Not Found
Failed to load image \EFI\BOOT\mmx64.efi: Not Found
Failed to start MokManager: Not Failed
Something has gone serious wrong: import_mok_state() failed: Not Found
```

Переустановить собираюсь в последнюю очередь, если совсем никак, а то мне столько чего надо устанавливать еще.

Comment: А вы хотя бы с LiveCD/LiveUSB загрузиться можете? Если да, переустановите grub через него

Comment: О, Спасибо, Andreymal. Помогло, успешно восстановил.. 
Спасибо огромное..